# xcode : undefined symbols when including headers

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, linker-errors

I recently started a project using swift and c++. So I installed Xcode and started using it. I first encountered some bugs, but fixed theme.

However, I still got some `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:`

I searched online and I can't find the solution for my problem (otherwise I would not have asked the question).

This is the whole error :

```
  "parser(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >, Node*, int, int)", referenced from:
      utilise_file(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, bool, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main.o
  "recognize_paternes(Node*, bool)", referenced from:
      utilise_file(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, bool, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main.o
  "ast_t_rep(Node*, int)", referenced from:
      utilise_file(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, bool, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main.o
  "lex(char const*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >&)", referenced from:
      utilise_file(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, bool, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main.o
  "visitor(std::__1::vector<Node*, std::__1::allocator<Node*> >, bool, bool, bool)", referenced from:
      utilise_file(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, bool, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But I think we can just consider :

```
      utilise_file(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, bool, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main.o
```

as this error seems to be redundant.

In my `main.cpp` file, I imported the header file (`parser.h`) where I declared `Node *parser(vector<string>, Node *, int, int);`.

In `main.cpp>utilise_file(...)`, I call the function `parser`:

```cpp
void utilise_file(){
    ...
    vector<string> code_ref = vector<string>();
    vector<string> lexeme = lex(source.c_str(), code_ref);
    Node *ast_t = new Node();
    ast_t->value = "main";
    ast_t->type = "root";
    Node *p = parser(lexeme, ast_t, 0, int(lexeme.size()));
   ...
}
```

So normally, I would not get this error.

It seems to me that it is a '*type*' sort of problem, but I can't figure what.

I searched online for solutions, and I tried adding `-Xlinker` in Xcode>Linking>Other Liner Flags, but it didn't helped.

I also thought of adding the flags linking to the header in the compiling command line, but I think Xcode does that automatically. (Or not because many of my headers are not recognized in the file arborescence...)

Thank you for your help ;)

**Edit** : I found the problem, I had to manually add the previously written header files in Xcode (which did not do it automatically).

Comment: You need to learn the difference between a *declaration* (telling the compiler something exists somewhere) and a *definition* (the actual implementation). For example `Node *parser(vector<string>, Node *, int, int);.` is a declaration. `Node *parser(vector<string>, Node *, int, int); { /* Some code ... */ }` is a definition. If you have multiple source files in your project, you need to build with all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

When I imported the previously written header files in Xcode, Xcode did not attached them to the project.

I had to manually add theme, and now it works fine !

Comment: The errors in your questions is unrelated to any *header* files. You need to learn the steps needed to create and build a C++ program: 1) Edit source code; 2) Compile source code into object files; 3) Link object files and libraries into the executable. Header files are only involved in step 2. Libraries are only involved in step 3.

Comment: Except when the function in question is actually implemented in the header file, in which case ld gives me undefined symbol errors, even though the header is included in the build. I even tried including the header in the source files, but still the error.